# sound locator in android

Tags: android, audio

i create app : record voice and determine frequency of sound

```
package com.example.recordsound;

import edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;

import ca.uol.aig.fftpack.RealDoubleFFT;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;    // Audio source is the device MIC
int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;    // Recording in mono
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT; // Records in 16bit

private DoubleFFT_1D fft;                           // The fft double array
private RealDoubleFFT transformer;
int blockSize = 256;                               // deal with this many samples at a time
int sampleRate = 8000;                             // Sample rate in Hz
public double frequency = 0.0;                      // the frequency given

RecordAudio recordTask;                             // Creates a Record Audio command
TextView tv;                                        // Creates a text view for the frequency
boolean started = false;
Button startStopButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
    startStopButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){      

        /*Calculates the fft and frequency of the input*/
        //try{
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioEncoding);                // Gets the minimum buffer needed
            AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioEncoding, bufferSize);   // The RAW PCM sample recording



            short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];          // Save the raw PCM samples as short bytes

          //  double[] audioDataDoubles = new double[(blockSize*2)]; // Same values as above, as doubles
       //   ----------------------------------------------- 
            double[] re = new double[blockSize];
            double[] im = new double[blockSize];
            double[] magnitude = new double[blockSize];
       //   ----------------------------------------------------
            double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];

            tv.setText("Hello");
           // fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(blockSize);


            try{
            audioRecord.startRecording();  //Start
            }catch(Throwable t){
                Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
            }

            while(started){
                /* Reads the data from the microphone. it takes in data 
                 * to the size of the window "blockSize". The data is then
                 * given in to audioRecord. The int returned is the number
                 * of bytes that were read*/

                int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);

                // Read in the data from the mic to the array
                for(int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {

                    /* dividing the short by 32768.0 gives us the 
                     * result in a range -1.0 to 1.0.
                     * Data for the compextForward is given back 
                     * as two numbers in sequence. Therefore audioDataDoubles
                     * needs to be twice as large*/

                   // audioDataDoubles[2*i] = (double) buffer[i]/32768.0; // signed 16 bit
                    //audioDataDoubles[(2*i)+1] = 0.0;
                    toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0; // signed 16 bit

                }

                //audiodataDoubles now holds data to work with
               // fft.complexForward(audioDataDoubles);
                transformer.ft(toTransform);
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Calculate the Real and imaginary and Magnitude.
                for(int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++){
                    // real is stored in first part of array
                    re[i] = toTransform[i*2];
                    // imaginary is stored in the sequential part
                    im[i] = toTransform[(i*2)+1];
                    // magnitude is calculated by the square root of (imaginary^2 + real^2)
                    magnitude[i] = Math.sqrt((re[i] * re[i]) + (im[i]*im[i]));
                }

                double peak = -1.0;
                // Get the largest magnitude peak
                for(int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++){
                    if(peak < magnitude[i])
                        peak = magnitude[i];
                }
                // calculated the frequency
                frequency = (sampleRate * peak)/blockSize;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                /* calls onProgressUpdate
                 * publishes the frequency
                 */
                publishProgress(frequency);
                try{
                    audioRecord.stop();
                }
                catch(IllegalStateException e){
                    Log.e("Stop failed", e.toString());

                }
            }

    //    } 
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... frequencies){
        //print the frequency 
        String info = Double.toString(frequencies[0]);
        tv.setText(info);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(started){
           started = false;
           startStopButton.setText("Start");
           recordTask.cancel(true);
       } else {
           started = true;
           startStopButton.setText("Stop");
           recordTask = new RecordAudio();
           recordTask.execute();
       }

}

}
```

how detect locate of sound with phone ?
i want arrow display and rotate to sound direction .
thank you...
possible with android phone for sound locator ?
or
create a robot or external sensor ?
thx

Comment: I do not think a single device like a phone can be used for figuring out the direction from which the sound came. You need more than one sensor for that and separate signals from all the sensors so you could compare the signals. Smartphones are not good enough for that even if you build a distributed application which will compare recordings from several devices.

Comment: You need **at least** 2 microphones (stereo location). It's like depth for vision: you need **2** eyes to perceive depth.

Comment: smartphone have two microphone one for send voive when calling and another for record voice when video capturing ...

Comment: Mind to tell us *which* device you have? My devices ALL have only **1** microphone and they use it for calling, sound capturing, dictation, OK googling, ... everything.